# What does a hat or star means in math?

Tags: notation

What are the general uses of the hat and star symbol in math? Or could you please point me to a page that discusses this? Thanks.

Comment: @Martino8: actually, when you write star symbol, could you please also provide it in latex? thanks!

Comment: Lots of things. Could you be more precise about what you're asking for?

Comment: Why don't you provide some context? We can probably make a list of 50 different uses of any given symbol, but that doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different branches of mathematics may have varying conventional usages of these kind of "decorations".  Typically they denote a transformed version of the base variable (e.g. $\hat{f}$ denoting the Fourier transform of $f$ as mentioned in another answer).  Or, they may denote a special or specific value of a variable ($x^*$ giving the value of $x$ minimizing $f$ from another answer.)  The $*$ symbol is often used for arbitrary associative binary operations.  Etc. etc.

Comment: Not to mention Kleene's star!

Comment: Absolutely!  I guess the point is that there is no "standard" usage across all of mathematics, though there are "local" conventions.  (Set theorists will have different conventions than K-theorists...)

Answer (score 11):

There is a nice list for $*$ in this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk)

I guess another (more general) term for "hat" is [Circumflex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex)

Answer (score 5):

how about omitted terms
$$
\partial\langle x_0,...,x_n\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\langle x_0,...,\hat{x_i},...x_n\rangle
$$

Answer (score 4):

I have seen the star used for multiplication, hermitian conjugate of a matrix, special values of a variable (given a function $f(x), x^*$ might be the value of $x$ that minimizes $f$), among others.  In Conway's theory of games, * is the game that wins for the first player.

Answer (score 3):

$\hat{}$ can also be used to denote the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of an integrable function $f$.

$\ast$ can be used to denote the convolution product $f \ast g$ of two functions $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 3):

According to [ISO 31-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11):
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{N}^* = \mathbb{N}-\{0\} \\
\mathbb{Z}^* = \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}
\end{align}$$
The same goes for $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$.
$$\begin{align}
z^* = \text{complex conjugate of } z.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I've seen $\mathbb{R}^*,\mathbb{C}^*$ used more to denote the hyperreals and hypercomplex numbers than that, tbh.

Comment: Shouldn't it be written as $\mathbb{N}^* =\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ and the same applies for $\mathbb{Z}^*$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The **Hat** symbol can be used to denote a vector. And the **Star** symbol may possibly used to denote a binary operation. For example a non empty set $G$ with a binary operation $\star$ is said to be  a Group if.....

Comment: I have also seen it denoting a unit vector.

Comment: @Ross: Unit vector is also a vector :)

Comment: True, but in these cases an overarrow was a vector of any length and the hat was reserved specifically for unit vectors.

Comment: @Ross: Perhaps, but i have used this symbol to denote vector quantities as well.

Comment: I'll second Ross's comment: I have always seen the hat used to denote a unit vector. Sometimes $\vec x$ is a vector of arbitrary length and $\hat x$ a unit vector; sometimes $\mathbf x$ is an arbitrary vector and $\hat{\mathbf x}$ is a unit vector; but never is a hat placed on a vector that is not of unit length.

Comment: I've also seen the $\hat{}$ symbol used with the $\hat{0}$ vector as well as $\vec{0}$.

Comment: I've seen $T^*$ denoting the adjoint operator of $T$, a bounded linear operator between two Hilbert spaces (for example, might be between other spaces perhaps)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: if $V$ is a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, its dual space, $V^*$, is the set of linear maps $V \to \mathbb{F}$. The dual space is also a vector space in its own right. The double dual of $V$ is $V^{**} = (V^*)^*$, and there's a nice correspondence between $V$ and $V^{**}$ such that given an element $v \in V$ we have a special corresponding element often called $\hat{v} \in V^{**}$.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through *generating functions* in [this paper](http://maths.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/ProbMC2H/_files/handouts/1516GeneratingFunctions2H.pdf), on pp. $16$, a paragraph states the following: $$\begin{align} &\text{In general, we say a sequence $(c_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is the convolution of $(a_k)_{k\geq 0}$ and} \\ (b_m&)_{m\geq 0} \ \text{$($write $c=a\star b)$, if}\end{align}$$ $$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}, \qquad n\geq 0, \tag{4.5}$$ I believe this provides the definition of the star $\star$ operation, precisley adding to what @RudytheReindeer mentioned.