# What is $\hat{\gamma}$ used in this example?

Tags: notation

I am reading [an article about support vector machine (PDF)](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf) and one part of the document the author talks about the optimal margin classifier.

In the excerpt below, I do not understand why the author is switching from  $\gamma$ to  $ \hat{\gamma}  $

> [image: support_vector_machine]

I found in this question, [What does a hat or star means in math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26222/what-does-a-hat-or-star-means-in-math) , that it can be used to denote a vector but the author already use the notation $\gamma^{(i)} $ when talking about a vector and earlier in the paper he says that

$$ \gamma = \min_{i=1, \dots , m} \gamma^{(i)} $$

so for me $\gamma$ is a vector too.

Bonus question: how should I read $ \hat{\gamma}  $   ?  "hat gamma" ?

Comment: I think "gamma hat" is how most people read it.

Comment: I think $\widehat{\gamma}$ is just a notation for a new variable. Maybe there is a typo in the document, beacause in the second optimization problem, one might expect the maximum to be taken over $\widehat{\gamma},w,b$ and not $\gamma,w,b$.

Comment: @jibounet yes I was expecting that too